# how to open new window on form close?

Tags: c#, winforms

how to open form 1 on close button click X in form 2
i tried this but it is not working:

```
private void supplierShow_FormClosing(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    new suppliersList().Show();
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Have you registered the close event anywhere?

Comment: where it will need to register?

Comment: You need to have a `this.Close += supplierShow_FormClosing;` somewhere. See this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xwbwks95.aspx

Comment: Thank you, but need use this.Closing += supplierShow_FormClosing;

Comment: No, actually use the FormClosing event.  You don't want to show a new form when the user is shutting down Windows.  Pay attention to the passed e.CloseReason.  Use the lightning bolt icon in the Properties window and double-click FormClosing to get this correct.

Answer (score 1):

Not fully sure without knowing more your code but to me it looks like you are declaring a local variable (new suppliersList of base class Form probably) and showing the form from the Closing event of another form.

Your Form2 object is probably going to be deleted/disposed/garbage collected soon and at that point I am not completely sure that the form declared within that scope would still have a nice life.

If Form2 is the application form, the application will actually terminate when you close it.

in general I think that this kind of form switching is best done and controlled from the main method, the same place where you probably have `Application.Run(new Form2());` because in there you have full control of the application flow and MessageLoops...

Answer (score 0):

I have to solutions:

**First:**

You may have a unique reference to your suppliersList in Program class:

```
public static suppliersList SuppList = new suppliersList();
```

you can now hide it if you want:

```
Program.SuppList.Hide();
```

you can show it anytime, too:

Program.SuppList.Show();

Be carefull! Don't `Dispose` SuppList. If you did, assign to it a new object `new suppliersList();`. Please note that this solution would success only if form1 is not the main form (i.e. `Application.Run(new form1());` )

**Second:**

You can start `form2` as a child of window of `form1`:

```
new suppliersList().Show(this);
```

because, as in the other answer, the application loops are on form1. If form1 is closed, then entire application will be closed too. However, starting a child window of the main window will prevent application close.

If the answer is useful for you, please mark it as your best answer.

Comment: Its not application loop it is actually message pump. i dont like your first option. i like your second one more but still i would not create a new child when closing, a that point better to simply hide and not close.

Comment: @Davide Yeah. He can also cancel the closing with e.Cancelled = false; then hide the form, then he can Show his form2...

Comment: Oh-Oh. The form will be Disposed after it is closed, from MDSN. I'll edit the answer.